# Connection string in appsettings.json for remote database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, connection-string, remote-connection

I have hosting account in `plesk` panel. I can create and remove a database in hosting panel.

Now I want to create a database from my local computer using add-migration in code first approach. but the following error occurs:

> "login failed for the user [myUserId]"

The connection string in `appsettings.json` is:

```
"CourseConnection": "Data Source = host-ip,1433; Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=myuserid;Password=mypassword"
```

There are two options to create databases on hosting panel:

```
localhost:3306(default for mysql)
localhost(default for MS sql v13.0...)
```

I think that provider name is not mentioned in `connectionstring` but `appsettings.json` works fine on my local machine without provider name: `System.Data.SqlClient.`

Comment: According to the error message, it seems that you used the wrong user myUserid. I suggest you could try to re-check you have used the right username and password.  Besides, if you want to use mysql for EF core, you should use `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` .More details, you could refer to this [article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of try and error , the problem solved as follows:
i created the database in plesk panel and created a new user .
then assign that user to the database . then  in `package-manager-console` applied `update-database` command to apply migration that was already added.
i used the same connection string in appsettings.json ,it worked successfully.all table created and migration applied .
it may be helpful for someone.
regards